# Marketo Custom Objects REST API giving incorrect FilterType Error

Tags: marketo

I am trying to consume Marketo Custom Objects REST API. Below is the endpoint which I am trying to consume

```
Endpoint: GET /rest/v1/customobjects/{{customObjectAPIName}}/list.json?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN&filterType=eventuserid&filterValues=EVENT_USER_ID&fields=eventid,eventtitle,eventdetails
```

This is giving me error as below:

```
{
    "requestId": "4d4b*******",
    "success" : false,
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "1003",
            "message": "Invalid filterType 'eventuserid'"
        }
     ]
}
```

Please pour your valuable suggestion on this how to get the below fields from Marketo Custom Objects API

> answeredpolls
>
> answeredsurveys
>
> archiveminutes
>
> askedquestions
>
> attendedarchive
>
> attendedlive
>
> Breakoutname1
>
> Breakoutname2
>
> Breakoutname3
>
> Breakoutname4
>
> Certificationwidgetresult1
>
> Contactuswidgetname1
>
> Ctadate1
>
> Ctaname1
>
> Engagementscore
>
> Partnerref

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the API names you've provided, I would first question whether those are accurate—Marketo tends to push using camelcase by default. If you run https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/lead-database/custom-objects/#describe, you should get the exact field names in REST API format back for querying against.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to get the detail of the Custom Objects by passing the "personId" as the filterType and some known Ids as the filterValues, but now I am looking for a way to know all the Lead IDs which are associated with a custom object. I could not find any endpoint which can give me all the PersonId who are linked with a CustomObject say "Car". Once I will get that then I can retrieve all the details for those Leads Custom objects information.  Please guide me with that.

Comment: @sac: Unfortunately, there's nothing out of the box with an API call alone that will produce that. However, there is a way forward: if you create a Smart List within Marketo constraining on "Has CustomObject Car: True", then pull that list via Bulk Lead Export, you should get the end result you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the activities and leads endpoints?

There should be an activity type ID (an integer of "id") associated with leads with custom object activities, just as there are ids associated with out-of-the-box lead activities like "open email" and "change data value" (which have activity type IDs of 10 and 13, respectively).

Try GET /rest/v1/activities/types.json to describe all of the activity type IDs in your instance, then query leads by filtering against the activity type IDs you're looking for.

There are limits in the number of leads the API will return, so I believe you'll also need to pass paging tokens. Given Marketo's data retention limits on lead activities, you'll probably want to setup a bulk extract process for lead activities anyway, which you could then query custom object activities using sql.

Reference:

- https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Activities/getAllActivityTypesUsingGET
- https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Leads/getLeadsByFilterUsingGET
- https://nation.marketo.com/t5/product-discussions/lead-activity-type-id-for-a-specific-activity-type/td-p/325349